# Solve the special integral

Tags: improper-integrals

I want to solve a integral which contains a shift version

$$\int^{\infty}_{c}N [(1-e^{-1/t})]^{N-1} \frac{-1}{(t-c)^2}e^{-1/(t-c)}dt$$

This kind of integral has the form of normal integral

$$ \int _{c} ^{\infty} {N [ f(x) ]  ^{N-1}} f(x)  ^{'} d(x)=f( \infty)  ^{N} -f(c)  ^{N} $$

However, in this case, the integral has the form of

$$ \int _{c} ^{\infty} {N [ f(x) ]  ^{N-1}} f(x-c)  ^{'} d(x), $$

where
$$ f(x) = (1-e^{-1/t}), $$

$$ f(x-c)^{'} = \frac{-1}{(t-c)^2}e^{-1/(t-c)}$$

I try to replace ($t-c$) by u, then $x=1/u$ and some more substitutions. However, the integral is still complex and difficult to solve.

$$ \int _{0} ^{\infty} N [1-e^{-x/(1+cx)}]^{N-1} e^{x} dx$$

Can I solve this kind of integral by some estimation techniques or near optimal solutions?

Thank you very much!